# Nokogiri stripping attribute namespaces during parsing

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I have this:

```
<style:style style:name="MYBOLD" style:family="text" style:parent-style-name="Standard">
  <style:text-properties style:font-name="Arial" style:font-name-complex="Arial" fo:font-weight="bold" style:font-weight-asian="bold" style:font-weight-complex="bold"/>
</style:style>
```

Note how the attributes have a namespace.

When I parse it like so:

```
Nokogiri::XML.fragment(xmltext)
```

It seems to have lost the namespaces for both the tags and the attributes!  Is there any way I can preserve those?

Comment: Why are you processing it as a fragment instead of parsing the whole document?

Comment: Because it's a fragment that will be added elsewhere in the document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nokogiri is blind to namespaces except (1) those on the root node, and (2) any that you register yourself. Since a fragment by definition has no root node, you'll have to supply namespace information yourself.

I noticed that the constructor to [DocumentFragment](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/DocumentFragment.html) has an optional Context node, from which it can glean namespace information. Since you have indicated in your comments that you have a document in which you will insert the fragment, as long as the namespaces are properly registered in that document you can probably use it for the context information.